# Как установить Play-2.6 на сервер

Tags: java, sql, playframework

Всем привет, я новичок в Play и никак не получается его задеплоить.

Программа на Джаве, локально все работает, ОС локально Винда. Пытались установить на сервер (Убунту), но ничего толком не получается. Прошелся по оффициальной документации, но на комманде

$ unzip my-first-app-1.0.zip
$ my-first-app-1.0/bin/my-first-app -Dplay.http.secret.key=abcdefghijk

получаю

>

команды как run, start на нем уже не возможны.

Также пробежался по туториалам, толкового ничего нет. Может у кого были свои заметки или кто-то делал.

Спасибо большое за ваше время.

Comment: It's ruSO. You need create question on Russian language

Comment: спасибо сейчас изменю, соррян запутался

Comment: И название тоже, плиз

Comment: все, готово спасибо большое :)